# How do I get rid of these errors in my code? NumberFormatException: for input string: ""

Tags: java, priority-queue, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:169)
```

These errors continue to pop up when I run my code against our sample input. We are given a document with polygons and have to use kruskal's algorithm and build a minimal spanning tree to find the shortest distance to each island without creating a cycle. If anyone can help or give advice on how to get rid of these errors that would be great! I dont understand how there can be a numberformatexception on a string ""....

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloWorld {
static class Point {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(x: " + x + " y: " + y + ")";
    }
}

static class Polygon {
    int numberOfVertices = 0;
    ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

    public Polygon(int numberOfVertices, ArrayList<Point> points) {
        this.numberOfVertices = numberOfVertices;
        this.points = points;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            Point point = this.points.get(i);
            stringBuilder.append(point);
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}

static class PQItem implements Comparable<PQItem> {
    int node1;
    int node2;
    double edge;

    public PQItem(int node1, int node2, double edge) {
        this.node1 = node1;
        this.node2 = node2;
        this.edge = edge;
    }

    public int compareTo(PQItem T) {
        if (edge - T.edge < 0)
            return 1;
        else if (edge - T.edge > 0)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

}

public static void BuildMinimalSpanningTree(int numberOfIslands, ArrayList<Polygon> polygons) {
    PriorityQueue q = new PriorityQueue((numberOfIslands * numberOfIslands) / 2);
    PQItem Temp;
    int[] CheckPad = new int[numberOfIslands];
    int FootPrint = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    double length = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < polygons.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < polygons.size(); j++) {
            Temp = new PQItem(i, j, ShortestDistance(polygons.get(i), polygons.get(j)));
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < polygons.size(); i++)
        CheckPad[i] = -1 - i;
    while (counter < polygons.size() - 1) {
        Temp = (PQItem) q.Remove();
        for (int i = 0; i < polygons.size(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < polygons.size(); j++)
                if (CheckPad[Temp.node1] != CheckPad[Temp.node2]) {
                    if (CheckPad[Temp.node1] < 0 && CheckPad[Temp.node2] < 0) {
                        CheckPad[Temp.node1] = FootPrint;
                        CheckPad[Temp.node2] = FootPrint;
                        FootPrint = FootPrint + 1;
                    }

                    else if (CheckPad[Temp.node1] < 0) {
                        CheckPad[Temp.node1] = CheckPad[Temp.node2];
                    }

                    else if (CheckPad[Temp.node2] < 0) {
                        CheckPad[Temp.node2] = CheckPad[Temp.node1];
                    }

                    else {
                        if (CheckPad[Temp.node1] < CheckPad[Temp.node2]) {
                            for (i = 0; i < polygons.size(); i++) {
                                if (CheckPad[i] == CheckPad[Temp.node2])
                                    CheckPad[i] = CheckPad[Temp.node2];
                                else
                                    for (j = 0; j < polygons.size(); j++)
                                        if (CheckPad[j] == CheckPad[Temp.node2])
                                            CheckPad[j] = CheckPad[Temp.node2];
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println(Temp.edge);
                        length += Temp.edge;
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
    }

}

static double ShortestDistance(Polygon polygon1, Polygon polygon2) {
    double shortestdistance = 0;
    double Temporary = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < polygon1.numberOfVertices; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < polygon2.numberOfVertices; j++) {
            Temporary = Math.pow(polygon1.points.get(i).x - polygon2.points.get(j).x, 2)
                    + Math.pow(polygon1.points.get(i).y - polygon2.points.get(j).y, 2);
            if (Temporary < shortestdistance)
                shortestdistance = Temporary;
        }
    return Math.sqrt(shortestdistance);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of the file");
    File file = new File(scanner.nextLine());
    try {
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);

        int numberOfIslands = Integer.parseInt(fileScanner.nextLine());
        ArrayList<Polygon> polygons = new ArrayList<Polygon>();

        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
            String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
            ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
            // PQItem NewItem = new PQItem(Node1, Node2, edge);
            // info.Insert(NewItem);

            for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i += 2) {
                Point point = new Point(Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]), Integer.parseInt(numbers[(i + 1)]));

                points.add(point);
            }
            // build tree

            Polygon polygon = new Polygon(points.size(), points);

            polygons.add(polygon);
            // BuildMinSpanTree(numberOfIslands, polygons);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < polygons.size(); i++) {
            Polygon polygon = polygons.get(i);
            System.out.println(polygon);
        }

        int minimalInterconnect = 0;
        int totalLength = 0;

        System.out.printf("The minimal interconnect consists of %d bridges with a total length of %d",
                minimalInterconnect, totalLength);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

HERE IS THE SAMPLE PROGRAM
3
4  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0
4  2  0  2  1  3  1  3  0
3  4  0  5  0  5  1

```
public class PriorityQueue {
private Comparable[] HeapArray;
int Last, Limit;
```

PriorityQueue

```
public PriorityQueue(int Capacity) {
    HeapArray = new Comparable[Capacity + 1];
    Last = 0;
    Limit = Capacity;
    return;
}
// end constructor

public PriorityQueue() {
    HeapArray = new Comparable[101];
    Last = 0;
    Limit = 100;
    return;
}
// end constructor

public void Insert(Comparable PQI) {
    if (Last == Limit) {
        System.out.println("Priority Queue Overflow!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // end if

    HeapArray[++Last] = PQI;
    this.UpHeap(Last);
    return;
}
// end public method Insert

private void UpHeap(int k) {
    Comparable V;

    V = HeapArray[k];

    while (k > 1 && HeapArray[k / 2].compareTo(V) < 0) {
        HeapArray[k] = HeapArray[k / 2];
        k = k / 2;
    }
    // end while

    HeapArray[k] = V;
    return;
}
// end private method UpHeap

public Comparable Remove() {
    Comparable PQI;

    if (Last == 0) {
        System.out.println("Priority Queue Underflow!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // end if

    PQI = HeapArray[1];
    HeapArray[1] = HeapArray[Last--];
    this.DownHeap(1);
    return PQI;
}
// end public method Remove

private void DownHeap(int k) {
    Comparable V;
    int j;

    V = HeapArray[k];

    while (k <= Last / 2) {
        j = k + k;

        if (j < Last && HeapArray[j].compareTo(HeapArray[j + 1]) < 0)
            j++;
        // end if

        if (V.compareTo(HeapArray[j]) >= 0)
            break;
        // end if

        HeapArray[k] = HeapArray[j];
        k = j;
    }
    // end while

    HeapArray[k] = V;
    return;
}
// end private method DownHeap

public boolean IsEmpty() {
    if (Last == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    // end if
}
// end public method IsEmpty

public boolean IsFull() {
    if (Last == Limit)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    // end if
}
// end public method IsFull

public int Length() {
    return Last;
}
// end public method Length
```

}
// end class PriorityQueue

Comment: When debugging your code, please create a [mcve]. This will often times allow you to find the issue quickly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

This is self explanatory. The input is expected as number however the input entered is String ""

The line that reads input and expects the value to be interger :

```
 int numberOfIslands = Integer.parseInt(fileScanner.nextLine());
```

Provide correct input.
Also you could change the `.nextLine()` to `nextInt()`

Comment: so I should change nextLine to NextInt??

Comment: @csgirl does it work after you enter the correct input as interger?

Comment: I changed it to NextInt but still got wrong error. I'm not sure what you mean by inputting correcting vallue because I'm reading from a file. How can I change the input if  I don't know what it is

Comment: does the file have first field as integer value? can you paste the first few rows in file? Is the error still on line 169 in above same program?